# implementing price of item using BigDecimal in java

Tags: java, bigdecimal

In a web application ,I want to model an *ItemForSale* which has a price field.I read elsewhere that float or double should not be used for currency fields due to rounding errors and BigDecimal is the proper type for this purpose.I created these classes

```
class ItemForSale {
    private String name;
    private BigDecimal price;
    ...
}

class MyUtils{
    ...
    public static BigDecimal parsePriceOfItem(String priceStr){
        BigDecimal price;
        BigDecimal zero = new BigDecimal(0);
        try{
            price = new BigDecimal(priceStr);
        }catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
            price = zero;
        }
        if(price.doubleValue() < zero.doubleValue()){
            price = zero;
        }
        return price;
        }
    }
```

Is this the right way to parse a price string(as entered by user)?I wanted to treat negative and invalid strings (say 'abcd') as 0.

If there is a better way ,please tell me

thanks

mark

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why would you want to treat invalid input as 0? Surely you'd want to tell the user that they've made a mistake, rather than treating it as if they'd typed in zero.

If you're parsing user input, you should probably be using `DecimalFormat` instead of the `BigDecimal` constructor - that way it will use the appropriate cultural information. (Use `setParseBigDecimal` to make `DecimalFormat` parse to `BigDecimal` instead of `double`.)

Then instead of converting the BigDecimal values to doubles, use:

```
if (price.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) < 0)
```

I would suggest that you should indicate to the user three different states:

- Number can't be parsed
- Number was negative (or possibly invalid in some other way; do you have a maximum value, or a maximum number of digits)?
- Number was valid

Answer (score 3):

How costly is your most expensive item?  If it is less than $21,474,836.47 you can safely express the price as a number of cents held in a normal `int`.

You are correct to avoid `float` and `double`.  The usual solution is to use an `int`, or a `long`, to hold the number of cents and adjust output formatting accordingly.  There is usually no need to get into the complexities, and speed issues, of `BigDecimal`.

Comment: +1: Or with a `long` you can have 92,233,720,368,547,758.07 If you have amounts larger than this, use BigDecimal ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Yes, you could use a scaled integer, but why on earth would you? A BigDecimal **is** a scaled integer, so ideal to represent currencies. It can also handle percentages in any way you like. Why re-invent the wheel and do what BigDecimal already does? Constantly scaling integers is not faster than using BigDecimal.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis BigDecimal is a reasonable alternative, however is still cumbersome and doesn't have any language support. This means reading and validating the code is much harder. It creates more garbage, though it is the developer overhead and maintainability of using BigDecimal which is it's biggest problem IMHO. On balance I would recommend people learn to use `double` properly (with rounding) and this is the easiest to maintain in my experience.

Comment: @Peter: I agree that a little more language support would make things easier, but still, if you concoct your own routines that scale integers or longs, that is not better than using a thoroughly tested library class. I don't see a big maintainability issue but YMMV. Yet, most people don't know how to use doubles properly, even seasoned programmers, so doubles would be my last choice..

Comment: @RudyVelthuis I can understand what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my suggestion:

```
public static BigDecimal parsePriceOfItem(String priceStr) {
    try {
        BigDecimal price = new BigDecimal(priceStr);
        return price.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) < 0 ? BigDecimal.ZERO : price;
    } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
        return BigDecimal.ZERO;
    }
}
```